# Could not load NIB from my own Pod

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, bundle, xib

I have a CalendarCell.xib and a CalendarCell.swift UIView subclass in my Pod framework. CalendarCell.swift has outlets connected to its view. At runtime I get this error:

> Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'CalendarCell'

In my podspec file I created a bundle resource:

```
s.resource_bundles = { 'Resources' => ['MyFramework/**/*.{xib,xcassets}'] }
```

If I install my Pod I can see the xib file but it crashes and now it seems that the xib file and its swift counterpart are in different bundle.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right, the xibs are stored in a different bundle. You need to find the path of the xibs bundle and load all the xibs from that bundle, instead of loading them from the main bundle.

To find the path of the bundle, in Swift 3:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: YourClass.self)
```

So, you have to load your `UINib` from that bundle:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "YourXibName", bundle: bundle)
```

and register it to your `UITableView`/`UICollectionView`, if you need it for this purpose:

```
self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

Comment: For some reason I couldn't make your solution work, but I figured out the right way.
`let bundle = Bundle(for: CalendarCell.self)
 let nib = UINib(nibName: "CalendarCell", bundle: bundle)` Thanks for your help, saved my day :)

Comment: Yes, there could be some differences, maybe in the way you organize the Pods project or files. This solution worked for me. Anyway, the general way is to load xibs from a different bundle. Thank you too :)

Comment: `bundle.loadNibNamed("YourClass", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first as! YourClass` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what I am using in swift, it works with main bundle and framework as well**

```
extension UINib {
    func instantiate() -> Any? {
        return self.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first
    }
}
extension UIView {

    static var nib: UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: Bundle.init(for: self))
    }

    static func instantiate(autolayout: Bool = true) -> Self {
        // generic helper function
        func instantiateUsingNib<T: UIView>(autolayout: Bool) -> T {
            let view = self.nib.instantiate() as! T
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = !autolayout
            view.autoresizingMask = []
            return view
        }
        return instantiateUsingNib(autolayout: autolayout)
    }
}
```

**To init view use**

```
let myView = MyView.instantiate()
```